# How do you cluster push pins in the Silverlight Map Control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, bing-maps

I have a Silverlight app where I'm using the Bing Map control and I've got about 2000 push pins. The performance is a bit sluggish, and I wanted to know how to cluster the push pins to increase the performance.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest using multiple layers and then on different zoom levels reveal different layers.. i dont know how your pushpins are arranged so i cant suggest any concrete clustering method.. but you can group them based on distances between them, and then on lower zoom level just show one element that represents the whole group

here's a way to calc distances.. 
http://silverlightfoundry.blogspot.com/2009/07/bing-maps-silverlight-control-part-5.html